# scrapy-linkedin for LinkedIn data extraction

Tags: python-2.7, scrapy

I'm using scrapy-0.16 for data extraction from LinkedIn.

```
    from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
    from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
    from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
    from scrapy.http import Request
    from scrapy import log
    from linkedin.items import LinkedinItem, PersonProfileItem
    from os import path
    from linkedin.parser.HtmlParser import HtmlParser
    import os
    import urllib
    from bs4 import UnicodeDammit
    from linkedin.db import MongoDBClient
```

https://github.com/pondering/scrapy-linkedin

The error comes

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\TAWANE DUDEZ\Desktop\linkedin\linkedin\spiders\LinkedinSpider.py", line 6, in <module>
    from linkedin.items import LinkedinItem, PersonProfileItem
ImportError: No module named linkedin.items
```

Cannot find `linkedin.items` module.

Comment: show us your directory structure ....

Comment: i couldn't get u please elaborate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My suspicion is that you're trying to run the `scrapy crawl LinkedinSpider` command from the wrong directory. Try navigating to `C:\Users\TAWANE DUDEZ\Desktop\linkedin` and then running the command again.

Since the crawler is now starting, you also need to be running a MongoDB instance before starting the crawl. The README of the github project being used says to type`mongod` to start an instance. Just to check, you do have MongoDB and pymongo installed right?

Comment: i ran going into the right directory but now it is showing the error
'no connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

Comment: Are you starting a MongoDB instance before running scrapy?

Comment: no still working on the configuration of mongodb cannot start it

Comment: Since we've resolved the original import error issue with the crawler, it would be best to tick this answer and then to create a new question for the MongoDB configuration issue since those are two different problems. :)

Comment: thanks for help but plz guide me for mongodb because the code is still not working

Comment: Sure. Please create a new question and provide details of why MongoDB is not starting/working.